# How can I write a loop to get many values from a solution?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations

I am looking at the value of `x[t]` at day `t = 200` over several years. I tried to do it using a For-loop but it didn't work. This is my loop:

```
For[i = 0, i <= 365*years, i++, 
  ss = 
    Table[Flatten[{200 + 365*i, Evaluate[x[200 + 365*i] /. s]}], {t, 0, 365*years}]]
```

So I am solving, copying and pasting values for each data point, which is takes a lot of time when there a lot of points. Any idea on how to do this with a loop?

My code:

```
Clear[ss];
a = 0.1;
b = 0.01;
k = (10*Cos[t] + 20);
years = 3;

s = 
  NDSolve[{x'[t] == a*x[t]*(1 - (x[t]/k)) - b*x[t], x[0] == 15}, 
    x, {t, 0, 365*years}];

ss = Table[Flatten[{t, Evaluate[x[t] /. s]}], {t, 0, 365*years}];
data = 
  {{200, Evaluate[x[200] /. s]}, {565, Evaluate[x[565] /. s]}, {930, Evaluate[x[930] /. s]}}

Clear[s]
data1 = 
  {{200, 15.07308029753746}, {565, 15.36783034746959}, {930, 15.704159312861188}};
ListPlot[data1, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Comment: @march  Thank you for your suggestion it works. Since I am looking for day 200 each year I used {t, 200, 365*years, 365}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, one tends to get the most out of `Mathematica` by trying to avoid explicit loops (e.g. `For`, `Do`, etc) in favor of functional expressions (e.g. `Map`,  `Fold`, `Nest`, ...).

If I understand what you are looking for, all you need is the following:

```
(* YOUR CODE *)
Clear[x];
a = 0.1;
b = 0.01;
k = (10*Cos[t] + 20);
years = 3;

s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == a*x[t]*(1 - (x[t]/k)) - b*x[t], x[0] == 15}, x, {t, 0, 365*years}];

(* NEW CODE *)
data = {#, x[#] /. First@s} & /@ Range[200, 200 + (years - 1)*365, 365]

ListPlot[data,
 PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05],
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.025], AxesLabel -> {"day", None}
]

(* Out: {{200, 15.0731}, {565, 15.3678}, {930, 15.7042}} *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Alternatively, you could obtain the same results using a `Table` construct:

```
data = Table[{t, x[t] /. First@s}, {t, 200, (years - 1)*365, 365}]
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am looking for.  Thanks that works.